# VoIP app don't maintain connection in 3G

Tags: ios, sockets, call, voip, 3g

Currently I'm developing a VoIP application. In wifi connection keeps me perfectamente. The problem is when I use 3g. After about 6 minutes in the background, and VoIP socket doesn't receive any call. But apparently it's connected. The problem isn't SIP server as this allows me to renew the registration after 10 minutes. Any idea?
Thanks.

I add code:

```
AppDelegate *app = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
int misocket = zObtenerSocket();

CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket(NULL, misocket, &readStream, &writeStream);
CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream,   kCFStreamNetworkServiceType,kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP);
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamNetworkServiceType, kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP);

inputStream = ( NSInputStream *)readStream;
outputStream = ( NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
[inputStream setDelegate:app];
[inputStream setProperty:NSStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP forKey:NSStreamNetworkServiceType];
[outputStream setDelegate:app];
[outputStream setProperty:NSStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP forKey:NSStreamNetworkServiceType] ;
[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setKeepAliveTimeout:600 handler:^{
                                                               cierra_extra();
                                                               zbCerrar();
                                                               [inputStream close];
                                                               [outputStream close];
                                                               registrarse_bg();
                                                               }];
```

registrarse_bg() reopens the socket and create the again

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: can I ask what VoIP service are you using ?

Comment: I use my own SIP server. Powered by my company.

Comment: The problem was the carrier I was using. The carrier must have some problem by providing data service. I've tried with two different carriers and it seems to work perfect.